# How to perform an action in Prism's "OnNavigatingTo" for any and all classes

Tags: c#, xamarin, mvvm, prism

Given I have about 100 classes in my Prism application project, a project can become difficult to debug for other devs. I am looking for a way to show a toast when a user navigates to any page. This toast message will tell the user the respective view model page title of the current view.

```
public class AViewModel 
{
   public override void OnNavigatingTo(INavigationParameters parameters)
   {
      Toast("AViewModel")
   }
}

public class BViewModel 
{
    public override void OnNavigatingTo(INavigationParameters parameters)
    {
        Toast("BViewModel")
    }
}

public class CViewModel 
{
   public override void OnNavigatingTo(INavigationParameters parameters)
   {
      Toast("CViewModel")
   }
}

public class DViewModel 
{
   public override void OnNavigatingTo(INavigationParameters parameters)
   {
      Toast("DViewModel")
   }
}
```

Im looking to achieve such functionality without actually including `Toast("ViewModelName")` in every class. Is there a way I can override something and implement this?

Comment: If this question is about a WPF or Xamarin project, please add the corresponding tag to your question.

Comment: @thatguy, i have updated - its for Xamarin

Answer (score 0):

It is easy to achieve in few steps like below

1. Create a BaseViewModel class

   ```
   public class BaseViewModel : INavigationAware
    {
        string PageName { get; set; }
        public BaseViewModel(string pageName)
        {
            PageName = pageName;
        }
        public virtual void OnNavigatedFrom(INavigationParameters parameters)
        {
          //Methods gets called when current active page navigated to some other page
        }

    public virtual void OnNavigatedTo(INavigationParameters parameters)
    {
      //Methods gets called when current page is activated

      //System.Diagnostics.StackFrame stackFrame = new System.Diagnostics.StackFrame(1);
      //Toast(stackFrame.GetMethod().DeclaringType.Name);

      Toast(PageName);
    }
   }
   ```
2. Inherit BaseViewModel class for each of ur ViewModel class

   ```
   public class AViewModel : BaseViewModel {
     //Constructor
     public AViewModel() : base(nameof(AViewModel))
     {
        //Some code
     }
   ```

> ```
> //MethodA
> public void MethodA()
> {
>     //Some code
> } }
> ```

Note:-

> base(nameof(AViewModel))

I hope this will help

Comment: Thank you for the response. It does work but was trying to eliminating having to add a parameter into every ViewModel.